# Generate the Tree structure in the Asp.Net Mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, backend

I create a tree structure in Asp.Net MVC Core along with the possibility of operating on this tree, i.e. adding branches, leaves, editing, etc. And I have a question whether this implementation of generating this tree is ok? Are there better ways to do this?

Branch generation method called from the controller:

```
        public ActionResult GenerateNodes(int? parentId)
        {
            var listOfNodes = _context.NodeEntitie.Where(x => x.ParentNodeId == parentId);
            return PartialView(listOfNodes);
        }
```

Generated view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Tree10.Models.Node>


@if (Model.Any())
{

    foreach (var element in Model)
    {
        <li class="listElement" onclick="Select(this)" id="@element.Id">+@element.Name</li>

        if (element.HasChildrens())
        {
            <ol>
                @Html.Action("GenerateNodes", "Node", new { parentId = element.Id })
                @Html.Action("GenerateLeafs", "Leaf", new { parentId = element.Id })
            </ol>
        }

    }

}
```

The method of generating leaves from the controller:

```
        public ActionResult GenerateLeafs(int parentId)
        {
            var listOfLeafs = _context.LeafEntities.Where(x => x.ParentId == parentId);

            return PartialView(listOfLeafs);
        }
```

Generated view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Tree10.Models.Leaf>


@if (Model.Any())
{

    foreach (var element in Model)
    {

        <li class="listElement" onclick="Select(this)" id="l @element.Id">@element.Name</li>
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

ehh ok it was stupid. I did a better solution

```
@{ 

    void ShowTree(int? parentId)
    {
        var newNodes = Model.Where(x => x.ParentNodeId == parentId);

        <ul>
            @foreach(var element in newNodes)
            {
                <li>@element.Name</li>
                if (element.SubNodes.Any())
                {
                    ShowTree(element.ParentNodeId);
                }
            }
        </ul>

    }

    ShowTree(null);
}
```